# Why throw ValueError with int() builtin reading parts of lines from .txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, type-conversion, file-handling

This is a subroutine which reads from `studentNamesfile.txt`

```
def calculate_average():
'''Calculates and displays average mark.'''
test_results_file = open('studentNamesfile.txt', 'r')

total = 0
num_recs = 0
line = ' '
while line != '':
    line = test_results_file.readline()
    # Convert everything after the delimiting pipe character to an integer, and add it to total.
    total += int(line[line.find('|') + 1:])
    num_recs += 1
test_results_file.close()
```

[`num_recs` holds the number of records read from the file.]

The format of `studentNamesfile.txt` is as follows:

```
Student 01|10
Student 02|20
Student 03|30
```

and so on. This subroutine is designed to read the mark for all the student records in the file, but I get this error when it runs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 65, in <module>
  File "python", line 42, in calculate_average
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

This error is pretty explicit, but I can't figure out why it's being thrown. I tried tracing the value of `line[line.find('|') + 1:]`, but Python insists it has the correct value (e.g. 10) when I use `print(line[line.find('|') + 1:]` on the previous line. What's wrong?

**Update**: I'm considering the possibility that `line[line.find('|') + 1:]` includes the newline, which is breaking `int()`. But using `line[line.find('|') + 1:line.find('\\')]` doesn't fix the problem - the same error is thrown.

Comment: @Sharku didn't see that yet, let me have a look

Comment: @Sharku I think my question is slightly different, although they are similar.

Comment: Yes you are right. Your problem is slightly different. Damm it you caught me judging too fast :p I retracted my flag to not confuse others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
while line != '':
    line = test_results_file.readline()
```

When you hit the end of the file, `.readline()` returns an empty string, but since this happens *after* the `while line != ''` test, you still try to process this line.

The canonical (and much simpler) way to iterate over a file line by line, which is to, well, iterate over the file, would avoid this problem:

```
for line in test_result_file:
    do_something_with(line)
```

You'll just have to take care of calling `.rstrip()` on `line` if you want to get rid of the ending newline character (which is the case for your code).

Also, you want to make sure that the file is properly closed whatever happens. The canonical way is to use `open()` as a context manager:

```
with open("path/to/file.txt") as f:
    for line in test_result_file:
        do_something_with(line)
```

This will call `f.close()` when exiting the `with` block, however it's exited (whether the for loop just finished or an exception happened).

Also, instead of doing complex computation to find the part after the pipe, you can just split your string:

```
for line in test_results_file:
    total = int(line.strip().split("|")[1])
     num_recs += 1
```

And finally, you could use the stdlib's `csv` module to parse your file instead of doing it manually...

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not a numeric value. So, python throws the `ValueError` if it is not able convert it into integer. You can below code to check it.

```
def calculate_average():
  test_results_file = open('studentNamesfile.txt', 'r')
  total = 0
  num_recs = 0
  for line in test_results_file.readlines():
    try:
        total += int(line[line.find('|') + 1:])
        num_recs += 1
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Data: ", line[line.find('|') + 1:])
  test_results_file.close()
  print("total:", total)
  print("num_recs:", num_recs)
  print("Average:", float(total)/num_recs)
```

## readlines vs readline

```
from io import StringIO
s = 'hello\n hi\n how are you\n'
f = StringIO(unicode(s))
l = f.readlines()
print(l)
# OUTPUT: [u'hello\n', u' hi\n', u' how are you\n']

f = StringIO(unicode(s)) 
l1 = f.readline()
# u'hello\n'
l2 = f.readline()
# u' hi\n'
l3 = f.readline()
# u' how are you\n'
l4 = f.readline()
# u''
l5 = f.readline()
# u''
```

## readlines

If we use `readlines` then it will return a list based on `\n` character.

## readline

From above code we can see that we have only 3 lines in the `stringIO` but when we access `readline` it will always gives us an empty string. so, in your code you are converting it into an integer because of that you are getting the `ValueError` exception.

Comment: When I run this code the `except` clause is never executed - it's working! Did you change how the file is read?

Comment: @C.R.Yasuo yes. `for line in test_results_file.readlines():`. Please accept the answer and give an up vote.

Comment: But why does this work? What's different about iterating through the lines from `.readlines()` from reading each line with `readline()`?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach.

**Demo:**

```
total = 0
num_recs = 0

with open(filename) as infile:                            #Read File
    for line in infile:                                   #Iterate Each line
        if "|" in line:                                   #Check if | in line
            total += int(line.strip().split("|")[-1])     #Extract value and sum
            num_recs += 1
print(total, num_recs)
```